# Jobs and schedules - how do they work with each other?

Tags: cognos, cognos-bi, cognos-11

could please someone enlighten me?

I have a data set and I need this data set to be refreshed on the 5th and 15th of the month.
But there can only be one schedule per Cognos object, right?

Is this the optimal solution?

I setup a schedule on the data set itself for the 5th of Month.

Then I create a job and add that data set as a job step.

I schedule the job containing that data set (which includes its own schedule) for the 15th.

What happens on the 15th and how these two schedules work with each other?

(This could also apply to reports etc).

Many thanks

I went through the documentation and some online articles, but there is no definitive answer if a data set (or a report..) can have multiple schedules set.

Answer (score 0):

Lots here about reports and report views explaining how I handle schedules.  Substitute "dataset" and "job" and I think you'll get what you want.

One schedule per object leads to limitations.  I have found for reports that it is better to create a report view to handle the schedule.  I very rarely schedule a report anymore because I often end up needing more than one schedule or set of parameters.

Using a report view provides a means to not only create multiple schedules per report, by creating multiple report views, but also have those schedules send the reports based on independent sets of parameters.  For example, the regional VPs want reports showing their sales revenue for the month, but only for their regions.  I would create one report, then create a report view for the U.S. and a report view for Europe.  Both get sent on the 5th of the month.

Likewise, I could set up 2 report views to work around the scheduling limitations.  Say I want to send the same report on the 5th and the 15th.  I would create the report, then create 2 report views to handle the schedules.

So, to translate this to your need...
To refresh the same dataset on the 5th and the 15th, create 2 jobs that have the dataset as a step -- one job for each schedule.

Using jobs looks like the right thing to do for your use case.  I don't see another scheduling option for datasets.

Comment: Many thanks dougp. The relation between an object schedule, and a schedule of the job where this object is added as a step, is not documented.

Comment: Guess I will experiment and find out :)

Comment: "The relation between an object schedule, and a schedule of the job where this object is added as a step, is not documented."  If you are trying to find out what objects are tied to a schedule through a job, ask a new question for that.

Comment: ...or maybe update this question.  The question in the body (Is this the optimal solution?) doesn't align well with the question title.

Comment: I just reread your first comment.  There is no relationship between the object schedule and the job schedule.  That may be why the relationship is not documented.

Comment: Many thanks for your input dougp.

I always had the impression, that a job step can have its own schedule as well, however it's not the case.
With reports it's easier, as you described, by creating the report view. But multiple refreshes of the same data set seem not to be possible.
I can add the the same data set as job steps, as many as i want, but there can only be one schedule anyway - and that's the one schedule for the whole job.

Comment: However, i can create multiple jobs, put the same dataset in these jobs, and set different schedules on these different jobs, so problem solved :)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's what I said.  I have updated my answer in an attempt to be more clear.